# How can I destroy a session using this class from Wikihow?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL

And I want to know how can I destroy the session...I've tried:

```
$session = new session();
$session->start_session('_s', false);
$session->destroy(session_id());
```

But no luck, it doesn't display any errors and the session is still opened.

Comment: Would you edit your question to show how you are determining the session is still open? Have a look at the implementation to see if there is something more you can do to destroy it.

Comment: Try just `session_destroy()`.  The `session_set_save_handler()` in the constructor should make it correctly trigger the `$session->destroy` function.